# Probability that the average is within range

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, mean

I'm currently preparing for an exam, and I just can't seem to grasp how to go about the question given the following information:

Information:
A brick factory produce bricks whose length $X_i$ can be assumed normally distributed with mean length of $228 mm$ and standard deviation $4 mm$ ..

Question:
At the brick factory a random sample of $50$ bricks is taken and the average of the lengths calculated by $$\bar X=\frac{1}{50}\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$$
What is the probability that the average of the observed lengths $\bar X$, is within the range of $[227;229]$.

My thoughts:
In the question before this, I was asked to calculate the 0.95 CI and found it to be in the range: $220 mm < X < 236 mm$, so I would assume when we averaged the random sample of 50 bricks, the probability would be over $90$ pct.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know what the mean and standard deviation of $\bar{X}$ are?

Comment: I don't know anything besides what I stated under "Information:" .. So to sum up I know the overall mean of 228 and the standard deviation 4. But I of course know nothing about the values of the random sample of 50 bricks :)

Comment: Then you really need to _read_ your textbook instead of trying to solve this problem. The question I asked was not about the individual values of the random sample, but about the _average_ of the 50 values, that $\bar{X}$ in your "question" Do you know what $\bar{X}$ might be _expected_ to be? 228 mm? 220 mm?

Comment: Alright, I will do that instead.. $\bar X$ is expected to be  roughly 228 mm, roughly because we are estimating a proportion (50) of the original sample.

Comment: Think about what happens when you sum up normally distributed variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use some basic results about [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) and [variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)

- The expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations
- The expectation of a constant times a random variable is the constant times the expectation of the variable
- The variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances
- The variance of a constant times a random variable is the square of the constant times the variance of the variable

The two results about expectation mean that the distribution of a sample mean of identically distributed quantities has the same mean as the original variable. The two results about variance mean that the variance of a sample mean (of independent identically distributed variates) has variance that's the original variance divided by the sample size.

Hence the sample mean of a sample of 50 bricks has mean $228$ mm and standard deviation $\frac{4}{\sqrt{50}}$ mm.

- You also need that linear combinations of independent normal random variates will also be normally distributed.

As a result, the sample mean will be $\sim N(228,0.5657)$

From there you should be able to find the probability called for in the question.